# An example of for loop in C leading to an infinite loop

Tags: c, for-loop

The following program was cited as going into an infinite loop:

```
#include<stdio.h> 
int main() 
{ 
   int n; 
   for(n = 7; n!=0; n--) 
     printf("n = %d", n--); 
   getchar(); 
   return 0; 
}
```

On analyzing, I do find that at one point the value of n does become 0 and right then, the loop should terminate. 
Won't it happen such that when it enters the loop for the first time, the value is 7, then it becomes 6, and since that there are 2 post-decrements per iteration? 
But, why does that not happen?

Comment: because n was never equal to 0, there are two post-decrement operations, one in for-loop and other in printf, so 7-2=5,5-2=3,3-2=1,1-2 = -1, so your termination condition not satisfied, and int number rollback after -ve overflow and it keeps on in infinite loop.

Comment: Look carefully, there are two decrements per iteration.

Comment: Not am infinite loop though, just undefined behaviour when the `int` underflowed. If it was unsigned, then it would be an infinite loop.

Comment: Well, won't it happen such that when it enters the loop for the first time, the value is 7, then it becomes 6 and since that there are 2 post-decrements per iteration?

Comment: @Curiosity That's not how for loops work.

Comment: Can you kindly elaborate on that?

Comment: In this example,
 for(i=0;i<8;i++) 
{ printf("%d",arr[i]); } 
the first value printed is of arr[0] and not arr[1].
Then, why isn't i incremented here in the first iteration itself?

Comment: @Curiosity Please take a look at my answer; it discusses the loop in detail and might explain your confusion. If not, I'll be happy to add more explanation when I have a moment to do so.

Comment: I get it now. The updation happens at the end of every iteration, and only then the condition is checked. Am I right?

Comment: So, the sequence is 7 -> 5 -> 3 -> 1 -> -1.

Comment: @Curiosity That's correct.

Answer (score 3):

Each loop iteration actually decreases `n` by two, and the comparison `n != 0` always sees an odd value for `i` and hence never terminates.

In particular, just before the iteration in question, n is first decremented to 1 by `n--` in the loop header (since this must occur after the end of the previous iteration, just before evaluation of the condition `n!=0`).

Then, `printf("n = %d", n--);` is evaluated, printing `n = 1`, while *post*decrementing `n` to zero. After the end of the loop body, n is decremented again by `n--` in the loop header, making it -1, just before the condition `n!=0` is evaluated to determine whether the loop should continue.

As a result, `n!=0` is true every time it is evaluated (in particular, it is not evaluated at the instant that n is zero, since the `n--` in the loop header must first complete)

Comment: Thanks for adding the "this must occur after the end of the previous operation" verbiage.

Answer (score 1):

It's because of the second decrement in the print here:

```
for(n = 7; n!=0; n--) 
    printf("n = %d", n--);
```

That makes the sequence of checks against n go 7, 5, 3, 1, -1, ... There are an even number of values for an int so this will form a cycle upon underflow that leaves out the even numbers, including 0.

Remember that the for loop condition is evaluated just before each loop iteration, and after the decrement in the loop itself. It isn't tested while the loop is running.

Comment: When it enters the loop, right then there is no decrement, right?

For instance, in,
for(i=0;i<8;i++)
{
printf("%d",arr[i]);
}
the first value printed is of arr[0] and not arr[1].

Comment: Correct. `for(stmt; cond; inc) { body }` is essentially the same as `stmt; while (cond) { body; inc }`

Comment: So, why doesn't that hold here?

Comment: So, when it enters the loop for the first time, the value of n should be the initialized value only, and the first decrement should occur on the second iteration.

Comment: @Curiosity *"So, why doesn't that hold here?"* - it *does*. Your `body` includes an identical `inc`. as well. If you thought about your loop body separated from the inc you buried inside it, the equivalent loop for you would be `stmt; while (cond) { body; inc; inc; }` Now, run that on a piece of paper and see what it delivers on each iteration.

Answer (score 0):

try doing this

```
#include<stdio.h> 
int main() 
{ 
   int n; 
   for(n = 7; n>=0; n--) 
     printf("n = %d", **--n**); 
   getchar(); 
   return 0; 
}
```

Comment: This is fine. I get that. My point is this:
When it enters the loop for the first time, the value is 7, then it becomes 6 and since that there are 2 post-decrements per iteration. So, values are 4, 2 and 0 subsequently.

Comment: Why do you think it becomes 6?

Comment: For instance, in, for(i=0;i<8;i++) { printf("%d",arr[i]); } the first value printed is of arr[0] and not arr[1].
So, when it enters the loop for the first time, the value of n should be the initialized value only, and the first decrement should occur on the second iteration.

Comment: try this inside loop  printf("n = %d", --n);

Comment: @Curiosity did it help?